# What is the Difference Between Data and Information

Tags: sql, oracle

n regards to a relational database, what is the difference between data and information? From what I understand, data is simply text, numbers, dates, etc. that can be individually entered into a database, but have no real meaning on their own. But when organized into a table or queried by SQL statements, it becomes information.

Is this correct? If this is not correct, please give examples using the SQL language if possible.

Comment: Data can be explained as the values entered into the database. The resulting output of that data into something that returns something meaningful would be information. SELECT * FROM sailors; < takes data from database and if you had a Question: List all the sailors on record. Then the resulting data returned from that query is now information.

Comment: Could something as simple as "SELECT hire_date FROM employees;" to see all the hire dates of employees working for a company be considered information? Or even "SELECT hire_date FROM employees WHERE last_name = 'King';"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data can be any character,text,words,number,picture,sound or video and if its not but into context means little or nothing to humans however,computer can turn this data into information that can a human understand.

Example of Data :

```
Joe,Smith,1234,circle,salt,Ut84084,8015553211 (this is data has no meaning)
```

Example of Information :

If we organize this Data it becomes information like this :

Joe Smith
1234 circle
salt lake cit,Ut84084
(801)555-3211

This information about one called Joe Smith (Its Just example),Imagine you go to the police office to report about a theif So,the police said to you do you have any information about him so,you told him his Name,address,number and so on

Answer (score 6):

Differences between Data and Information did not come from Database techniques. In fact it's related to **System Theory**.

Based on **DIKW pyramid** (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIKW_pyramid): 
[image]

**Data** can be every thing that we know, every fact. (as being discrete, objective facts or observations).

In **Database Systems**, Data is every thing that we are saved in database.

**Information** is some data that can be refine, resulted, inferred or gained by analysis on data. It's based on Context Observer. Some process needs to making the data useful and turned to Information. Absolutely the amount of Information is less that Data at all.

In **Database Systems**, any data that can be resulted on analysis on it and make it useful in Context, can be Information. For example maybe just one query, results useful data in Context and usefulness of this resulted data is related to Observers of Context.

Data Mining Technologies, Web Mining Technologies, Big Data Analysis Technologies and etc are the examples of resulting Information from Data.

We can explain Knowledge and Wisdom like above approach.

Comment: Although I think that this is, to a large extent, a matter of opinion, I agree with and appreciate your opinion on this matter.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Thanks a lot. (I am greatly honored)